# Using a Key (for grouping) on a variable containing a node set

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

this is a cut down example of my xml

```
<Albums>
    <Album id="1">
        <info>sdkjsdaln</info>
    </Album>
    <Album id="2">
        <info>asdlnasd</info>
    </Album>
    <Album id="3">
        <info>sadsasd</info>
    </Album>
</Albums>
```

I use an extension function to get more data

```
<xsl:template match="Album">
     <xsl:variable name="Album" select="mfeg:GetAlbumMetadata(@id)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

I then have the variable $Album which I reference to get all the extra data, as shown below

```
<Album>
    <Tracks>
        <Track>
        <Contributors>
            <Contributor>Tim</Contributor>
            <Contributor>Alfie</Contributor>
        </Contributors>
        </Track>
        <Track>
        <Contributors>
            <Contributor>Tim</Contributor>
            <Contributor>Alfie</Contributor>
        </Contributors>
        </Track>
        <Track>
        <Contributors>
            <Contributor>Kevin</Contributor>
            <Contributor>Sam</Contributor>
        </Contributors>
        </Track>
    </Tracks>
</Album>
```

I am trying to get the unique Contributors, I dont know how / If its possible to use a Key on my variable $Album to get the data i require. I have tried the xpath below but it doesn't work.

```
$Album/Tracks/Track/Contributors/Contributor[not(.=preceding-sibling::Name)]
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well to define a key you simply use e.g.

```
<xsl:key name="k1" match="Track/Contributors/Contributor" use="."/>
```

then to apply Muenchian grouping you should be able to to

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="$Album/Tracks/Track/Contributors/Contributor[generate-id() = generate-id(key('k1', .)[1])]"/>
```

and then you can write a template for the Contributor elements. Note that you might need to adapt the path to e.g. `$Album/Album/Tracks/Track/Contributors/Contributor[generate-id() = generate-id(key('k1', .)[1])]`, depending on what kind of node (element or document node) your extension function returns.

Comment: ah simple as that! thanks will give it a whirl thanks! guess i was just overcomplicating things :P